# DataColumn's AutoIncrement Returns False Always

Tags: vb.net, oledb, datacolumn

I am interested to check out whether column has an autoincrement/allowdbnull property .

Having this code below , gives me always false although I already have one column that has autoincrement/allowdbnull property.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim con As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =" &             Application.StartupPath & "\test.mdb"
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * from teachers"
Dim i As Integer



Dim dataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
dataAdapter.Dispose()



For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns

TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & column.ColumnName & "      " & column.AutoIncrement & "        " & column.AllowDBNull & vbCrLf

Next
```

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make your code work you need to add (before the call to `Fill` method) just

```
  dataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
```

This will force the adapter to retrieve the information about primary keys and autonumber fields

MSDN [MissingSchemaAction enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.missingschemaaction.aspx)

Comment: Nice. Should mention this will slow your database calls down so this should not be done on a regular bases. If you need this on a regular basis, do it once in a seperate process asking for records "where 1=2" and then just use it all over the place, rather than calling it with every select command.

Comment: @Steve (I like talking to myself -:) ) your observation is correct. Adding the schema info slows down the data retrieval so not a thing to do on a regular base. However this is a Local Access MDB, so the performance hit should be not very bad. To be tested.

Comment: @Steve , thank you very much :)
Is there a way to get the "EXACT" dataTpe of column ?column.DataType.ToString ?
when I say "EXACT" i mean to get the specific type of field/column as mentioned here in this website :

[link](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_datatypes.asp)

because for different types such as Memo & Text -> I get System.String for both.

thanks

Comment: Try to post a new question, you could get more attention on new questions than adding a comment here. However I could give you an hint: `OleDbDataReader.GetSchemaTable()`

Answer (score 0):

```
ds = new dataset()

dataAdapter.Fill(ds,0,1,"Teachers")

dataAdapter.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "Teachers");

dt = ds.tables(0)
```