# Properly read the column data type in ms access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

How to properly get the Data Type of MS Access table

Below is my code:

```
var con = $"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                           $"Data Source={database};" +
                           "Persist Security Info=True;";
                using (OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection())
                {
                    myConnection.ConnectionString = con;
                    myConnection.Open();
                    DataTable dt = myConnection.GetSchema("Tables");

                    var l = myConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

                    var isTableExist = false;
                    foreach (DataRow item in l.Rows)
                    {
                        var tbleName = item[2].ToString();

                        if (tbleName == tableName)
                        {
                            isTableExist = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (isTableExist)
                    {
                        string sql = string.Format($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}");
                        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, myConnection))
                        {
                            using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (reader != null)
                                {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetName(i));
                                        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetDataTypeName(i));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Here is the structure of the mdb file im reading

[image]

And this is what i'm receiving

```
id
DBTYPE_I4
main_id
DBTYPE_I4
Document_ID
DBTYPE_WVARCHAR
End_page
DBTYPE_WVARCHAR
No_pages
DBTYPE_I4
```

Why does the AutoNumber datatype show the same as the number data type?

What i'm doing here is merging tables. And i want to skip the insert statement for those data type `AutoNumber` but i can't make it work because the result is the same with number. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataColumn's AutoIncrement Returns False Always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368015/datacolumns-autoincrement-returns-false-always)

Comment: Because the Autonumber really is a Long Integer. It has to be because a related foreign key must be Long Integer and linking fields must be same data type.

Comment: In VBA, the following returns true for Autonumber but false for others: `IIf(rs.Fields(i).Attributes And dbAutoIncrField, True, False)`